# How to get all supported collate in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

Is there any statement that could get all supported collates in an oracle database? For example, like pg_collations in PostgreSQL.

Comment: It seems NLS_VALID_VALUES view is a way to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/appendix-A-locale-data.html#GUID-CC85A33C-81FC-4E93-BAAB-1B3DB9036060) has a lot of information, but

```
select value from v$nls_valid_values where parameter = 'SORT';
```

| VALUE |
| --- |
| ARABIC |
| ARABIC_ABJ_MATCH |
| ARABIC_ABJ_SORT |
| ARABIC_MATCH |
| ASCII7 |
| AZERBAIJANI |
| BENGALI |
| BIG5 |
| BINARY |
| BULGARIAN |
| CANADIAN FRENCH |
| CANADIAN_M |
| CATALAN |
| ... |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ira32jDr)

As the documentation says:

> All the linguistic collations can additionally be specified as case-insensitive or accent-insensitive by appending _CI or _AI to the linguistic collation name respectively.