# Removing accents from string in PLSQL is slow

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I`m trying to make a PLSQL function (Oracle) that replace accents before perform a query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FNC_REMOVE_ACENTO(pString IN varchar2) RETURN varchar2 IS vStringReturn varchar2(2000);
BEGIN   
    vStringReturn := replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(pString, 'Á', 'A'), 'À', 'A'), 'Â', 'A'), 'Ã', 'A'), 'É', 'E'), 'È', 'E'), 'Ê', 'E'), 'Ë', 'E'), 'Í', 'I'), 'Ì', 'I'), 'Î', 'I'), 'Ó', 'O'), 'Ò', 'O'), 'Ô', 'O'), 'Õ', 'O'), 'Ú', 'U'), 'Ù', 'U'), 'Û', 'U'), 'Ü', 'U'), 'Ç', 'C');
RETURN vStringReturn;
END;
```

And I will use on a Java method, like:

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT *FROM USERS WHERE FNC_REMOVE_ACENTO(UPPER(NAME)) LIKE ?)));
 pstmt.setString(1, "%HÉRON%");
 ...
 iterator loop (it.next()) 
 ...
```

This is working, but it is very slow. When I remove the FNC_REMOVE_ACENTO function, it works very fast.

I also tried with translate method, like:

```
vStringReturn := translate(pString,'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü*','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu ');
```

This also works, but very slow too.

I can't use collate, like:

```
SELECT 'áéíóúç' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS;
```

Because unfortunately the oracle version of my client is old.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: Use the translate version and create a function-based index with the same translate expression. The issue isn't your string replacement but the inability to use indexes when you apply those functions.

Comment: how would I do this function? I'm new to PLSQL

Comment: I'll provide an exmaple in an answer

Comment: `SELECT 'áéíóúç' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS;` would only work in 23c. `SELECT 'áéíóúç' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS from dual` from 12c.
If you have a version that's Really Old, please specify which one it is, so its limitations can be taken into account.

Comment: oracle version 12.2.0.1. The SELECT 'áéíóúç' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS from dual command does not work: SQL Error [12746] [72000]: ORA-12746: unrecognized collation name "SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1251_CS_AS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slowness is not from the string replacements but from the inability use indexes for this lookup. To solve this, create a function-based index matching your function:

```
CREATE INDEX i_users_noaccent on USERS ( translate(UPPER(name),'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜ*','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEU '))
```

Then query with:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE translate(UPPER(name),'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜ*','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEU ') LIKE ?
```

Alternatively you can create a virtual column with this definition and index the virtual column. Same thing, different style, a bit cleaner because you have the definition in only one place.

I removed the lowercase from your translate mapping because the UPPER would make finding those characters impossible.

Also if you want to use `LIKE` you need to ensure you don't start the bind value with `%`, or you'll throw out index use that way as well. You can have a trailing `%`, but not a leading one.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still slow. The strange thing is that the query via Postman or via Dbeaver is fast, but inside Java it is slow. In Java, I'm simply populating a DTO with the data coming from the query, and this routine is fast. The slowness is during the execution of the query. And when I remove the PLSQL function from the PreparedStatement, it runs fast.

Comment: You would need to show the execution plan in use during your slow run, along with the code that shows the SQL you are using.

Comment: It's also possible to use collation in `create index` statement and use this collation to perform accent-insensitive search without manual translate: `create index on table(column collate binary_ai)`

Comment: @astentx, i'm actually not familiar with the collations.  I think it was one of those things I glossed over in the "What's New" back when. None of the examples I've seen folks offer seem to work for me. `binary_ai` makes no difference when I try it. `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS` which someone else above suggested errors when I try it. Is there a list of collation values somewhere that explains what each does? Are these collations something that have to be preinstalled manually?

Comment: @PaulW It's broadly described in Globalization support guide, but it is quite large and requires dig into some Unicode terminology. `binary_ai` seems to work on some basic examples: https://dbfiddle.uk/AxqwTWng. The list of possible collations may be obtained with this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74796771/2778710